# Is there an easier way to do content negotiated responses in Grails?

Tags: grails, controller, content-negotiation

From what is in the Grails user guide, the [recommended way](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#contentNegotiation) to send different content formats based on the content negotiation is to use a `withFormat` block:

```
import grails.converters.XML
class BookController {

    def list() {
        def books = Book.list()
        withFormat {
            html bookList: books
            js { render "alert('hello')" }
            xml { render books as XML }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would like the responses of ALL my controller methods to do this. Is there a better way to get this behavior than to simply copy-paste the `withFormat` block at the end of every content-returning action?

Answer (score 1):

First two things that popped in my head were Interceptors and Filters:

http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Controllers/afterInterceptor.html

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.6 Filters

Interceptors won't work because you can't do the withFormat.  Bummer because that's a more global.

Filters will work on a controller per controller basis, but at least you'd be minimizing your duplication at that level.

```
def afterInterceptor = {model, modelAndView ->
    withFormat {
        html { model }
        js { render "alert('hello')" }
        xml { render model as XML }
    }
}
```

This worked for me in my test project.  I tried putting that closure into it's own class and mixing in the class so that you could do a more global solution... no dice though.

Maybe have all of your afterInterseptors pass the model, modelAndView to a common class?  That seems to work :) (working towards an answer while answering)

```
@Mixin(AfterInterceptorWithFormat)
class FirstController {

    def action1 = {}
    def action2 = {}

    def afterInterceptor = {model, modelAndView ->
        performAfterInterceptor(model, modelAndView)
    }
}

class AfterInterceptorWithFormat {

    def performAfterInterceptor(model, modelAndView) {
        withFormat {
            html { model }
            js { render "alert('hello')" }
            xml { render model as XML }
        }
    }
}
```

Give that a whirl and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is to simply adjust the default CRUD templates to have the `withFormat` block at the end of each method.

I realized that what I *really* wanted was just content-negotiated CRUD, so putting the code into the templates was all I needed for that.

The rest of the controllers for the non-crud parts of my application did not need no-html output, so I didn't need content negotiation on anything but the crud controllers.